# what should i do if professors don't reply my mail for graduate admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I want to apply to study computer science phd at us universities, and I am wondering if a professor that I have emailed for admission don't reply my mail. should i still apply for university?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could start your sentences with capital letters.

Comment: Spam filters sometimes interpret non-capitalization, or all caps, or non-standard capitalization and other punctuation, as evidence of spam, just FYI... Even if the filter didn't get it, many people (including myself) do not take seriously emails from unknown people written ... carelessly or hastily.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, admissions are normally handled at the department level, so there's no reason you shouldn't apply, even if a potential advisor hasn't answered your email.

However, you may also want to consider the possibility that the advisor in question either didn't get it (it was sent to a spam folder, for instance), or overlooked it (it happens).